# Bluetooth unexpectedly ceased functioning during regular operation

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth, blueman

```
$ rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

It simply vanished. I was listening to music through my Bluetooth speaker when it suddenly disconnected.

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available

$ blueman-adapters 
blueman-adapters version 2.1.2 starting
blueman-adapters 12.24.46 ERROR    Adapter:53 __init__  : No adapter(s) found
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting or power cycling?

Comment: Power cycling tends to work as long as the computer stays shutdown for a while. But it keeps happening. Last time it took around 90 days of 24/7 operation for the problem to occur. The machine isn't supposed to have any downtime, though.